# How to connect to a docker container from host(windows machine)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine

i am literally new to Docker. I have a java application which I can execute by using javaws command as below.
j**avaws http://localhost:9088/rtccClient/rtcc.jnlp.**
I have created docker container for this application in my window's machine using "ibmcom/websphere-liberty:latest" as base image. after starting the container I am executing the same command to run the application and it says "CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: http://localhost:9088/rtccClient/rtcc.jnlp]".
Below is my docker file . please update what I am doing wrong.

```
**FROM ibmcom/websphere-liberty:latest
USER root
ADD ./rtcc.ear /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps
ADD ./rtccClient.war /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps
RUN yum -y install unixODBC
RUN yum -y install libaio
RUN mkdir -pv /basic
COPY ./basicinstaclient/oracle-instantclient19.8-basic-19.8.0.0.0-   1.x86_64.rpm /basic/
RUN rpm -i /basic/oracle-instantclient19.8-basic-19.8.0.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
EXPOSE 9088
EXPOSE 9450**
```

when I inspect the docker container id the ip showed as "172.18.0.3" and port of the container was 9080. In jnlp file which I mention in the javaws command I am supposed to use the ip and port. do I need to put ip and port of the container?
so I used "javaws [http://172.18.0.3:9080/rtccClient/rtcc.jnlp"](http://172.18.0.3:9080/rtccClient/rtcc.jnlp%22). still it didn't work. I even replaced with my windows machine IP. I even logged into container to execute javaws command. it says javaws not found. **Please help**

Answer (score 0):

Try a command like this:

```
docker run -p 9080:9080 YOUR_IMAGE_NAME_HERE
```

then try the `javaws http://localhost:9088/rtccClient/rtcc.jnlp` again

the -p will map ports like this: `host:docker` from left to right map the host machine port to the docker internal port.

Here you can also find a nice docker FROM scratch workshop (shameless plug) : https://docker-from-scratch.ivonet.nl/

Answer (score 0):

I tried as you said and this is what i am getting. CouldNotLoadArgumentException[ Could not load file/URL specified: http://localhost:9088/rtccClient/rtcc.jnlp]

More over you are mapping 9080:9080 in run command and using 9088 in javaws command. so how it will work?